# Pausing iPhone game from applicationWillResignActive

Tags: iphone

I am trying to pause my app when the user hits the home button.

Here is how I pause the game in the GameViewController:

```
- (void)pauseGame

{
     if (!gamePaused) {

    [gameTimer invalidate];

    [self pauseLayer:self.view.layer];

    gamePaused = TRUE;

    }
}
```

AppDelegate.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#import "GameViewController"

@class GameViewController;



@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate> {    

    GameViewController *game;

}

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
```

AppDelegate.m

```
@interface AppDelegate()

@property (readonly) GameViewController *game;

@end


@implementation AppDelegate

@synthesize window = _window;



-(GameViewController *)game

{

   if (!game) {

      game = [[GameViewController alloc] init];

    }

    return game;

 }


- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application

{

   [self.game pauseGame];

}
```

This doesn't give me any errors or warnings, but it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: when you press the Home button, do you go into `applicationWillResignActive:` (i.e. set a breakpoint there) and if you do, can you step through your pauseGame method?

Comment: it know it does go into applicationWillResignActive, so it must be something with calling pauseGame...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I believe the event you want to use for the home button is called something like applicationDidEnterBackground. Try putting your code there also.  The event you are using is useful too because it gets called if a phone call comes in or the device locks.

Comment: K, I added  [self.game pauseGame]; to applicationDidEnterBackground but still the same result...